# Can you please identify this tree?

Tags: identification, trees

I'm looking for this tree type. Can anyone recognise it please?

[image]

Comment: Welp, can't go by form as it is topiaried.  Please send a close up of leaves.  This is not by any stretch a normal tree, needs lots of professional pruning.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm not sure how to find the tree again. We drove past it and my wife took the picture from the moving car. This is a close up of the same picture. I hope it helps. http://postimg.org/image/5w4moa77z/

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't really help - too out of focus to see leaf detail clearly, and that's what we'd need. This tree has been cloud pruned, by the way...

Comment: Where is this, the Maryland shore? We're doing kind of a nice imitation of a Monteray pine, but I'm pretty sure that's not it.

Comment: Treehugger!  This has got to be either a cedar or a juniper.  Pines would have NEEDLES which I am not seeing. Kinda weird though...someone else has taken a picture of this same tree (maybe I am hallucinating) for some other question.  Or these people just were trying to capture Japanese theme.  LOVE your name...lots of people to include my parents isn't that incredible!!  Go for another drive...this has got to be close where you live yes?  When you do find this, take pictures of the bark as well as the leaves and any cones you might find.

Comment: The main thing to focus upon is WHAT about this tree is it that you like?!!  Couldn't be the specific tree...the topiary, the gravel, the simplicity...what do you think?